# Accepting or rejecting $H_0$ for a different size of sample

Tags: statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

> Two researchers are testing the hypothesis that says:
>
> $H_0 : \mu = \mu_0$
>  $H_1 : \mu > \mu_0$
>
> For a known variance and the same significance level. Both researchers
>   got the same $\bar{x}$ in their modeling, researcher **A** based on
>   sampling a population of $100$ and researcher **B** based on a
>   sampling population of $200$.
>
> I. If researcher A rejected $H_0$, what would researcher B do?
> II. If
>   researcher A didn't reject $H_0$, what would researcher B do?

As far as I know when you take a larger sample of the population you're most common to miss actual change (marked $\beta$) and less common to have false-positive (marked $\alpha$), that means that in case **I**, since $\alpha$ of researcher **B** is smaller than **A**'s and **A** has rejected $H_0$, then **B** will most definitely reject it as well. Now case **II** mixed everything in my head once again. I tried plotting the normal distribution function and find the relevant areas but got it all mixed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. For Part I, the test statistic for $A$ is $10(\overline{x}-\mu_0)/\sigma$ and for $B$ it is $\sqrt{2} \times 10(\overline{x}-\mu_0)/\sigma$ which is bigger, so if $A$ rejects then so will B. For Part II, you are also right. We cannot answer the question, it depends on $\overline{x}$.

For example, suppose $\mu_0=0$ and $\sigma=1$. Then if $\overline{x}=0$, both tests give a $P$-value of $0.5$ so neither would reject at the $5\%$ level. But if, say $\overline{x}=0.16$ then the $P$--value for $A$ would be 
$$P(Z > 10(0.16-0)/1 ) = P(Z > 1.6) = 0.055$$ 
and for $B$ it would be 
$$P( Z> \sqrt{2} \times 10(0.16-0)/1) = P(Z> 2.26) = 0.011$$
where $Z \sim N(0,1)$, so in this case $A$ would not reject $H_0$ at the $5\%$ level, but $B$ would reject.

(PS. Check the first sentence after the grey box in your post. Is it the wrong way round?)

Edit: here is my attempt to draw it. [image]

This is if you fix the Type I error rate $\alpha$ and increase $n$. The grey area is the type I error and the blue area is the type II error $\beta$, for a particular alternative value $\mu_a$ of $\mu$. As $n$ increases the type II error gets smaller as the type I error is held fixed. The curves are the sampling distributions of $\overline{x}$ under $H_0$ and $H_a: \mu=\mu_a$ for increasing values of $n$.

Comment: Could you help me understand how would $\alpha$ and $\beta$ look on a normal plot, and what would happen to them as $n$ gets bigger? And yes, the sentence is wrong way around, thanks.

Comment: Woah, I wish I could +100 you and not just +1. Thank you so much, this is super helpful.